# Is it possible to redirect from react component inside laravel blade view to another blade view

Tags: reactjs, laravel, routes, laravel-blade, laravel-5.6

I believe this question might be weird. But I am developing laravel application and I used `react` to create a part of `HomePage`. Now in this react component there is element I want to click and redirect to another `blade.php` view.

Before I added this React view I was sure nothing like that would be implemented, but now something has changed and it needs to be done.

I can't really even imagine a way to do that since React has no access to Laravel routing. If anyone could tell me if there is a solution to that or I have to get rid of React and remake it into blade.php to make this happen.

Comment: Can't you just use a normal link?

Comment: Not a problem. I'll write up a little answer for you to mark as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a normal link, and Laravel will sort the rest out for you